# Is there any way to suppress a sent SMS message from appearing on the sending phone?

Tags: c#, xamarin, sms

I'm using the following code to send a SMS message in the background using Plugin.Messaging:

```
    public async void SendSMS(string pMessage, string pPhoneNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;
            if (smsMessenger.CanSendSmsInBackground)
                smsMessenger.SendSmsInBackground(pPhoneNumber, pMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.LogError("App: OMLAndroid (TextMessage.cs) - An error occurred when trying to send a text, the error is: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Once the permissions are set properly, the SMS gets sent with no issues. Because there's a possibility that a user can send a lot at once, is there anyway I can suppress the display of the message in the messages app?

I can see hundreds of copies the same message being displayed with all the different numbers, all the answers I've seen suggest no unless your app is set as the default message system. I don't want the users to have to do that, but if there's no other way, it is what it is and I can instruct users to workaround that by setting my app as the default temporarily (ugly).

Comment: I read the relevant document about [SMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/sms?tabs=android) and some other things. It seems that app can only be set as the default message system.

Comment: Yeah, I read the same, was hoping there was something most folks didn't know.  Guess not.  Oh well, thanks.